# React Native with Apollo can't connect to Graphql server in Heroku

Tags: heroku, react-native, react-apollo, graphene-python

I'm been working in a project to test Graphql and is working fine in the server, but I can not connect my React Native app to the "API" server that is configured in Heroku with Django + Postgress + Graphene. You can test it here: https://hosting-api.herokuapp.com/graphiql

I choose Apollo for the React Native app to manage the connection following this example: http://dev.apollodata.com/react/simple-example.html

The app works ok with the default URL: http://api.githunt.com/graphql but when I change to my server I got the error in the image. 403 is the code for forbidden, but I have already added '*' to the allowed_hosts and cors_origin_whitelist. Also, when I change to another URL, e.g. my blog, it returns a 200 error which is ok because I don't have Graphql configured there but at least the app can make a connection.

Any ideas or suggestions?

[image: error message]

Answer (score 0):

Try to check django log, in my case trouble was with CSRF token.

And fix looks like:

## urls.py

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^graphql', csrf_exempt(GraphQLView.as_view(graphiql=True))),
]
```